# What is the use for explicit intents between different applications in Android environment?

Tags: android, security, android-intent, permissions

Discussing about Android Security a question raised and we could not find a reasonable answer (maybe naive questions):

1. Why does an Android Application declare an activity/receiver/service in
   the manifest without an intent-filter and with the tag
   exported=true?
2. How another application can send an explicit-intent
   to the receiver declared as above? Please, give a code example if
   possible.
3. What are the implications about that?

Example found on Application Manifests:
package = "com.google.android.youtube"
Application: android:name="com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.YouTubeApplication"
Receiver: android:name="com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.notification.ExternalPlaybackControllerV14$RemoteControlIntentReceiver"
android:exported="true"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explanation for the example you have given is pretty easy. The example you've given is for a `BroadcastReceiver` component. This component has `android:exported="true"` so that it can be called from other components external to the application. A good example of this use is `AlarmManager`. If the application wants to use `AlarmManager` to set an alarm, the component which the `AlarmManager` calls when the alarm goes off **must be publicly available**. The reason is that `AlarmManager` must be able to start the component, even if your application is not running. To do that, the component must be declared in the manifest and it must be publicly available (ie: "android:exported="true").

In general, anytime your application creates an explicit `Intent`, and then passes this `Intent` (using `PendingIntent`) to another component that is external to your application, the component in question must be publicly available.

You asked for a code example. Another application could trigger the `BroadcastReciever` component you've given in the example like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube",
                    "com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.notification.ExternalPlaybackControllerV14$RemoteControlIntentReceiver");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Hope this answers all your questions.